# How to choose one of the three values for a new column in R?

Tags: r

I want to create a new variable in my dataframe. For this NewVar, I want to take values from three variables: Var1, Var2 and Var3. The condition is that
NewVar = If Var3 is NOT NA, then Var3, otherwise Var2
If Var2 is NA, then Var1.
In short, my first priority is Var3. If it is NA, then I want to go to Var2. And if Var2 is also NA, then I want to choose Var1.
How can I do it in R? I am open to using base approach or tidyverse or even data.table.

Comment: Could you give your sample datasets to do that? dput() function would be help to copy and paste your sample on this website.

Answer (score 0):

The `coalesce()` function from `dplyr` is your friend here. It takes select the first not missing value from a set of variables.

```
test <- data.frame(var3 = c(1, NA, NA), 
                   var2 = c(10, NA, 30), 
                   var1 = c(NA, 200, 300))

library(dplyr)
answer <- test %>% 
  mutate(answer = coalesce(var3, var2, var1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in base R using nested ifelse.

```
mydf <- data.frame(var3 = c("x", NA, NA), 
                   var2 = c(NA, "y", NA), 
                   var1 = c(NA, NA, "z"))
mydf$new.col <- ifelse(!(is.na(mydf$var3)), mydf$var3, ifelse(!(is.na(mydf$var2)), mydf$var2,ifelse(!(is.na(mydf$var1)), mydf$var1,"NA"))) 
mydf
```